# MongoError: topology was destroyed sailsjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

When I try to create this error shows up:

> Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
>   MongoError: topology was destroyed
>       at Server.insert (/Users/oscargallon/Documents/developer/sails/reyesmagoswebpae/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:797:49)

here's my model

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: 'String',
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        mobile: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: v0.11.2 fixes the connection issues introduced in v0.10.7 and  v0.11.0. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also encountered this same problem today - i changed the sails-mongo version from "sails-mongo": "^0.10.7" to "sails-mongo": "^0.10.6" in package.json in sails and ran $ sudo npm install then sails lift it worked fine i think there is some error in npm

Comment: Thanks men you just save my life, I do not know what is the issue with 10.7 version but the 10.6 is working

Answer (score 2):

Sails-mongo v0.10.7 introduced a breaking change and doesn't support mongo <= 2.4. The breaking change has been reverted and v0.10.8 was published restoring compatibility with mongo <= 2.4. Meanwhile v0.10.7 has been deprecated.

Simultaneously v0.11 has been released which is compatible with mongo >= 2.6.

For those using mongo <= 2.4 **do not** update to 0.11.x.

**UPDATE:** some users reported problems with Mongo 3.0 and using v0.10.8 seems to have fixed the issue for them: [more details](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/266#issuecomment-98203817).

**UPDATE 2:** The issue with v0.10.7 and v0.11.0-1 has been traced to inappropriate connection configurations ([PR #277](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/pull/277)). This can be fixed locally by adjusting the connection config (`sails/config/connections.js` file for sails users):

```
devMongodbServer: { // connection name
    port: 27017,
    database: 'dev-mongodb-server',
    poolSize: 5,
    socketOptions: {
        noDelay: true,
        connectTimeoutMS: 0,
        socketTimeoutMS: 0
    }
}
```

v0.11.2 will be released with this connection config as default.

More details on https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/266

Comment: I'm experiencing same problem: Sails.js v0.11.0, sails-mongo v0.11.0, Mongo 3.0.2, OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: Hi Jevgenijs, try using 0.10.8: [more details](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/266#issuecomment-98482051)

Comment: There is no more a 0.10.8 version !
It stops at 0.10.5 and going next to 0.11 oO

     npm ERR! version not found: sails@0.10.8

Comment: Dagnan, my answer refers to sails-mongo, there's where this issue lies. `npm info sails-mongo` reveals versions 0.10.8, 0.11.0 and 0.11.1.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Anandapriyan, it caused by 0.10.7 sail-mongo. The solution doesn't work for me but inspired me.
I re-install sail-mongo with a elder build. and it works.

```
sudo npm install sails-mongo@0.10.6 --save
```

I've tried 0.10.4 but I got another error. So just user 0.10.6

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
```

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer, it should be posted as a comment.