# sailsjs and mongodb err when work with data CRUD

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

In localhost work fine but when public to amazon. I got error during create post data to mongo

"error": "E_UNKNOWN", 
"status": 500, 
"summary": "Encountered an unexpected error", 
"raw": 
{ 
"name": "MongoError", 
"message": "topology was destroyed"
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959602/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed-sailsjs

Comment: Facing the same issue, looks like something has gone wrong in the latest versions.