# Odd "timeouts" when attempting to execute a MongoDB query from a Sails.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js, waterline

When I start my Sails application in a localhost environment and load it in a browser, the view will render fine, an async request to another (non-mongo) resource works fine, but any async requests back to Sails that fetch data from Mongo works only within the first few moments of app start.

I can hammer as many requests as I want so long as I get one request in in the first few moments.  Beyond that, if I wait a full 2 or 3 seconds, the call will always stall.

Here's an example of the query using native:

```
    Item.native(function (error, collection) {
      collection.find().sort({'count': 1}).limit(parseInt(count)).toArray(function(error, data) {
        console.log(error, data);
        return res.send(data);
      });
    });
```

And another example using Waterline:

```
Item.find().sort('count ASC').limit(count).exec(function (error, data) {
  console.log(error, data);
  return res.send(data);
});
```

When it stalls, the callback is never called, so no error ever gets logged to the console.

I've tried stepping through the code and and it seems the flow of logic just bounces around from an internal `_dispatch()` function, to a couple of `bind` functions and back and forth and on and on.

I can verify that queries work fine from the Mongo console, and I'm seeding my database using Waterline on app start and that's also working fine.  I can also access the collection fine (the first callback using `native` executes).  I feel like I'm starting to run out of ideas, so any help would be great.  Thanks for taking a look.

Here's what I'm running for reference:

- sails: 0.11.0
- mongo: 2.6.10
- sails-mongo: 0.11.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoError: topology was destroyed sailsjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959602/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed-sailsjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gconsidine, sails-mongo v0.11.0 and v0.11.1 have a bad connection configs. Check my answer on a previous thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973775/4249576. Try updating sails-mongo to v0.11.2.

Comment: Hah, glad I wasn't just going crazy.  I ended up using MySQL/sails-mysql just to continue development, but you're right, updating sails-mongo to v0.11.2 did the trick.  Thanks a ton.